# Is there a better way to extract numbers from a string in python 3

Tags: python, string, lambda, integer, python-3.8

I have strings of the form "V70N-HN" and I just need to get the 70 out. The first characters can be any number of letters, or none at all. Same goes for the final characters. I've used variations of this in the past, but it looked cleaner in python 2 without the 'join' and 'list' thrown in the mix:

```
>>> a = "V70N-HN"
>>> i = int(''.join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), a))))
>>> i
70
```

Anyways, this is not very pythonic anymore. Is there an easier, more understandable way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Use a regular expression: `\d+`

Comment: You don't need `list()`. `join()` works with any sequence.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: Yours will gite 701 for "V70N-H1" - is that supposed to be that way?

Comment: You don't *need* list. But using a list comprehension is more pythonic than `map`/`filter`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, I only expect digits sandwiched between other characters. It's a pretty regular syntax, so not too much of an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I wasn't aware of "Code Review". I'll look into that for next time.

Comment: @VioChemist You should add that clarification to the question. Your code seems to be designed to combine multiple numbers, and several answers replicated that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way you can do the regex search that @Barmar suggested:

```
>>> import re
>>> int(re.search("\d+", "V70N-HN")[0])
70
```

Comment: I think I like this the best, although I need an extra import.

Answer (score 3):

Without regex:

```
>>> int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, a)))
70
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using list comprehension:

```
>>> int(''.join([i for i in a if i.isdigit()]))
70
```